# Inline if only seems to be called on first iteration asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if anyone could clear up what I'm doing wrong. To give you a whole shot of the situation here is the asp repeater;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="gdvCars" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><h1>Cars</h1><hr/></HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# IIf((Container.ItemIndex)/3 = 0 Or Container.ItemIndex=0, "<div class='row'>", "")%>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl= <%#Container.DataItem("Image_path")%> ></asp:Image>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3><%#Container.DataItem("Make")%> <%#Container.DataItem("Model")%></h3>
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr><th>Make</th><td><%#Container.DataItem("Make")%></td></tr>
                            <tr><th>Model</th><td><%#Container.DataItem("Model")%></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <%# IIf((Container.ItemIndex)/3 = 0, "</div>", "")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code above is a VB ASP.net script which is trying to loop through a data source returned by the database and on every third iteration create a new row, however the only time it appears to match is on the first iteration.

I can provide more information if needed, the rest it appears to work fine just the inline if statement;

```
<%# IIf((Container.ItemIndex)/3 = 0 Or Container.ItemIndex=0, "<div class='row'>", "")%>
```

and

```
<%# IIf((Container.ItemIndex)/3 = 0, "</div>", "")%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see:

```
0/3 = 0
1/3 = 0.33
2/3 = 0.66
3/3 = 1
4/3 = 1.33
5/3 = 1.66
...
```

so yes, it only returns `0` on the first iteration. Is it possible that you meant to do a *modulo operation* (`Container.ItemIndex Mod 3 = 0`) instead of a *division* (`/`)?